# Why does the following code show an error?

Tags: c, function, debugging, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>

void m();

void n() {
    m();
}

void main() {
    void m() {
        printf("hi");
    }
}
```

On compiling, an error

> "undefined reference to m"

is shown. Which `m` is being referred to?

Comment: First you should know that C doesn't support nested functions, if it works for you then it's because your compiler allows it, but it's not portable. Then think about scoping, you would not expect a local variable defined inside the `main` function to be available in the global scope would you?

Comment: there's only one m not defined - also there are no nested functions in ANSI C

Answer (score 3):

First, let me declare clearly,

> **[Nested functions are not standard `C`. They are supported as GCC extension.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)**

OK, now, in your code, `m()` is a nested function inside `main()`. It is having block scope for `main()` only. Outside `main()` other functions cannot see the existence of `m()` ,neither can call `m()` directly. `m()` can be called only inside `main()`.

In your case, the call to `m()` inside `n()` is causing the issue. Even if you provided the forward declaration as `void m();`, linker won't be able to find the definition of `m()` and throw error.

**Solution:** Move the definition of `m()` outside `main()`, then you can use it from any other function.

Also note, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

As has been explained elsewhere, C doesn't support nested functions as a rule (gcc does as an extension, but almost no other compiler that I know of does).

You need to move the *definition* of `m` outside of `main`.  Preferably you should define `m` before it is used by `n`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void m()
{
  printf("hi\n");
}

void n()
{
  m();
}

int main( void ) // void main() is not a valid signature for main
{
  n();       // call n, which calls m, which prints "hi"
  return 0;
}
```