# Undefined reference to function in C program

Tags: c, nested-function

I'm kind of new in C programming. To be honest this is my first program where I am using Function. But it's not working. Can anyone tell me what is supposed to be the problem?

```
// Convert freezing and boiling point of water into Fahrenheit and Kelvin

#include<stdio.h>

void calculation(int);
void freezingCalculation(void);
void boilingCalculation(void);

int main (){

int temperature, fahrenheit, kelvin;


void freezingCalculation(void){
   int temperature = 0;
    calculation(temperature);
 printf("Freezing point in Fahrenheit is %d. \n", fahrenheit);
   printf("Freezing point in Kelvin is %d. \n", kelvin);
}

void boilingCalculation(void){
    int temperature = 100;
    calculation(temperature);
    printf("Boiling point in Fahrenheit is %d. \n", fahrenheit);
    printf("Boiling point in Kelvin is %d. \n", kelvin);
}

void calculation(int temperature){
    //Temperature in fahrenheit
    fahrenheit = ((temperature * 9) / 5) + 32;

    //Temperature in Kelvin
    kelvin = temperature + 273;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with the actual details of the error message, line number or function that is not defined?

Comment: You might want to get a [a good book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/253056) before you write any more code - studying it will save you a lot of time and grief.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @ Paul R

Comment: There is no error massage now in the code. It is just not printing the statements. @ miltonb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you did not call your function.

Write your method (freezingCalculation etc) outside of main function and do not forget to return as your main function return type is integer.Like--

```
#include <stdio.h>
int temperature, fahrenheit, kelvin;
void calculation(int);
void freezingCalculation(void);
void boilingCalculation(void);

int main (){



    freezingCalculation();
    boilingCalculation();

    return 0;
}
void freezingCalculation(void){
   int temperature = 0;
    calculation(temperature);
 printf("Freezing point in Fahrenheit is %d. \n", fahrenheit);
   printf("Freezing point in Kelvin is %d. \n", kelvin);
}

void boilingCalculation(void){
    int temperature = 100;
    calculation(temperature);
    printf("Boiling point in Fahrenheit is %d. \n", fahrenheit);
    printf("Boiling point in Kelvin is %d. \n", kelvin);
}

void calculation(int temperature){
    //Temperature in fahrenheit
    fahrenheit = ((temperature * 9) / 5) + 32;

    //Temperature in Kelvin
    kelvin = temperature + 273;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's helped a lot. But i'm still not getting my results. Can you tell me why?

Comment: what result you want to see? did not it print all 4 statement ?

Comment: Yeah, i do. But nothing is printing. :(

Comment: here it is printing all 4 statement.Where you run this code? did you try my code?

Comment: My mistake. It is printing now. I miss typed two lines. Thanks a lot brother. Learned a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are trying to define functions *inside* the `main()` function. This is not allowed in pure C. [Some compiler extensions allows "nested functions", but that's not part of the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31076534/2173917).

What happens here is, the compiler sees the function declarations but cannot find any *definition* to the functions as they are not in *file scope*.

You need to move the function definitions out of `main()` and call the functions from `main()` as per the requirement.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is solved. Though it's not printing what i expected. It seems still i have some errors in the code.

Comment: @RubelHosen that is because, you're performing integer divisions. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39818803/2173917).